# Spring MVC jsp mapping

Tags: spring, jsp, http-status-code-404

Hello I am new to Spring and stuck on my jsp mapping - my pages give out the 404 - Page not found error.

**My Project Structure is**

```
    WebContent
     + META-INF
     - WEB-INF
      - jsp
        index.jsp
        login.jsp
      +lib
      springMVC-servlet.xml
      web.xml
```

Web.xml

```
     <display-name>spring</display-name>
        <servlet>
             <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
             <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
        </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <welcome-file-list> 
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

springMVC-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

        <context:component-scan
            base-package="web.controller" />

     <!-- Enabling Spring MVC configuration through annotations -->
     <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

HomeController

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
            public String index(){
                    return "index";
            }

            @RequestMapping(value="/login")
            public String login() {
                return "login";
            }
```

I am able to load the `http://localhost:8080/Spring3/`

The index.jsp has the following code -

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
       pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <c:url value="login.jsp" var="somevar" />
    <h1>Click here to </h1> <a href= "${somevar}">Login</a>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

However when I click the link to the login page - I get the 404 page.

I am not sure what is going wrong - Can anyone help me identify where my mapping is going wrong.

Comment: You're linking directly to a jsp page inaccessible to the client, use the spring controller mapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in index.jsp you should write `<c:url value="login" var="somevar" />` as your controler having mapping `@RequestMapping(value="/login")`